# 00:00 should be different from 12:00 in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a website that displays soccer matches and I want to display the time of the games according to timezone.
This is my script for converting timezone that displays the time:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-utc-time]").text(function () {
        var utcTime = $(this).attr("data-utc-time");
        return moment.utc(utcTime, 'DD.MM HH:mm a').local().format('DD/MM HH:mm');
    });
});
```

It displays everything correctly except when I try to order matches by time 00:00 and 12:00  are not two different things.
So I have:

1. 23:00
2. 23:40
3. 00:00
4. 13:00
5. 02:30

Comment: Removed `c#` tag, since it is irrelevant for this question

Comment: What’s doing the ordering?

Comment: For ordering i am using    datatables : "order": [1, 'asc'],